# Is there a way to tell if LocalBroadcastManager broadcasts were received?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

Is there a way to tell if LocalBroadcastManager broadcasts were received? Or are being listened to?

Basically I have an IntentService listening for Google Cloud Messages. When it gets one I need to either show a notification OR alert my main Service that there's been a new message - crucially I don't want both! So I need to know whether the message was dealt with by my main Service ...

Clearly it can be done with sendOrderedBroadcast and a BroadcastReceiver but that seems overkill for my simple private intra-process needs.

Comment: Why do you need two services in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare - because they have massively different purposes and lifecycles and it therefore improves my application architecture to separate them. One is an IntentService and the other is a bound service.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell if LocalBroadcastManager broadcasts were received? Or are being listened to?

`sendBroadcast()` returns `true` if there was 1+ receivers, `false` otherwise. That's not documented, but that is based on the current implementation. I filed [an issue to get that documented](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59626).

Hence, your `IntentService` could use `sendBroadcast()` to try to send a message to your running `Service`, if it exists. If it does, `sendBroadcast()` should return `true`, and the `IntentService` knows that the message should be handled there. If `sendBroadcast()` returns `false`, you can raise the `Notification`.

Comment: DUH! I even saw the boolean result and just thought it would mean that the broadcast was well ... broadcast. Thanks.

Comment: What a 'revelation' and relief that ***it indeed is*** what my guess was! Thanks @CommonsWare!