# LocalBroadcastManager broadcast not consumed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, localbroadcastmanager, android-jobscheduler

The `Intent`s I broadcast with `LocalBroadcastManager` don't seem to be consumed, but instead accumulate. Each time I send a broadcast, I receive both it and all previously sent broadcasts, in `onReceive`.

In a periodical `JobService` I'm creating a `BroadcastReceiver` with an `IntentFilter` and registering it dynamically with `lbm.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);`. I then start a `Service` which creates an `Intent` with the same filter in its constructor, and does `lbm.sendBroadcast(intent);` once, then stops itself.
`sendBroadcast` returns true which should indicate that it was received on the other end (see [Is there a way to tell if LocalBroadcastManager broadcasts were received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558979/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-localbroadcastmanager-broadcasts-were-received)). However each time this cycle is repeated, all the previously received `Intents` are received again. By bundling a timestamp I have confirmed that it's really the old ones just lying around and being received over and over again.

How do I "consume" the received `Intent`? From what I can tell this shouldn't be necessary if it was received by onReceive. I don't find any methods for cancelling a broadcast in either `Intent` or `LocalBroadcastManager`.

How can I receive each broadcast only once?

Comment: Make sure to unregister your BroadCastReceiver when the JobService is done.

Comment: I had indeed forgotten to do so before jobFinished in one place. Results are looking better so far. A ray of hope?! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Talha Mir who posted the solution as a comment.

I was only calling `unregisterReceiver` in `onStopJob`, not in other paths. Adding this fixed the problem.

Apparently a broadcast can stick around after `onReceive`, if the receiver isn't unregistered.